# Powershell + csv: read column 1, modify Content and write it down in column 2

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm really not that good in Powershell and only get along with a lot of Google research.

I have a CSV File and in column 1 are a bunch of words.

For Example:

```
Wild
Copy
Hell
Tom
Snow
```

I want to write a Powershell Script that reads in each row what is written in column 1, add characters to it and write it down in clumn 2.

For Example:

```
Coumn1 - Column2
Wild - Wildcat
Copy - Copycat
Hell - Hellcat
Tom - Tomcat
Snow - Snowcat
```

I dont really have something nearly working, I had something in mind like this:

```
$CSV = Import-CSV 'c:/Path2CSV'

ForEach ($row in $CSV)
{
    $Modified = Column1 + "cat"
    write $Modified > column2
    }
}
```

I would be so glad if anyone could give me a hint.

Thanks beforehand for any reply

Comment: This should be easy to help with, but It's not clear to me what your before data looks like or what the desired result is.  Can you add that in a tabular format? If not me I'm sure someone here can cook something up...

Comment: `Import-Csv` for files or `ConvertFrom-Csv` for strings are needed along with `Select-Object`. I could post an answer if you want spoilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input csv (the one with just one column) has a header above the values, read it with

```
$CSV = Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Path\To\input.csv'
```

If this file is just a series of words each on its own line and there are no headers, use

```
$CSV = Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Path\To\input.csv' -Header Column1
```

Then, when you have the data in variable $CSV, loop through and create a new csv:

```
$newCsv = foreach ($row in $CSV) {
    # output an Object that gets collected in variable $newCsv
    # Select-Object * takes everything already in $row, 
    # @{Name = 'Column2'; Expression = {$row.Column1 + 'cat'}} adds the extra column to it.
    $row | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Column2'; Expression = {$row.Column1 + 'cat'}}
}

# output on screen:
$newCsv

# output to new CSV file
$newCsv | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Path\To\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output (on screen):

```
Column1 Column2
------- -------
Wild    Wildcat
Copy    Copycat
Hell    Hellcat
Tom     Tomcat 
Snow    Snowcat
```

<sup>There are more ways of achieving what you want, the above just tries to stay as close as possible to your suggested pseudo code</sup>

Comment: The OP misspelled `Column1` so perhaps have some example data for this?

Comment: @Theo I hope you dont mind but I have a additional Question; If I have for instance declared the variable $Animal that represents Strings and Integer, how do I put that in Column3? Can I add it to the first $row | Select (...) Line or do I need to do a second $row?

Comment: @Ladi I'm not quite sure what you mean.. Is this $Animal also in the input CSV, what type of object is that? Probably best if you post a new question about that so you can provide examples.